# When I scroll to the right or left on html canvas I get image trails, why?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

When I move to the left or right on the canvas, I start getting these trails effect. I need it to be rendered nicely as it is in the center of the canvas. I use translate() function to move the background to the side. I also tried clearRect but then when I move to the right I just get the white background. How to fix this?

[image]

```
var view = {x: 0, y: 0};

var mapArray = [
  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
];

function render(viewport) {

  context.save();
  context.translate(view.x, view.y);



  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  var oldPosX = boatPosX;
  var oldPosY = boatPosY;


  for (let i = 0; i < mapArray.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < mapArray[i].length; j++) {

      if (mapArray[j][i] == 0) {
        this.sprite.draw(
          background,
          190,
          230,
          26,
          26,
          i * this.sprite.width,
          j * this.sprite.height,
          this.sprite.width,
          this.sprite.height
        );
      }
      if (mapArray[j][i] == 1) {
        this.sprite.draw(
          background,
          30,
          30,
          26,
          26,
          i * this.sprite.width,
          j * this.sprite.height,
          this.sprite.width,
          this.sprite.height
        );

      }
      if (mapArray[j][i] == 2) {
        this.sprite.draw(
          background,
          200,
          20,
          26,
          26,
          i * this.sprite.width,
          j * this.sprite.height,
          this.sprite.width,
          this.sprite.height
        );
      }
    }
  }
  this.ship.drawimage(boat, boatPosX, boatPosY, 50, 50);


  if(isPositionWall(boatPosX + 36, boatPosY)) {
    boatPosX = oldPosY;
    console.log("collision");
  }

  context.restore();

};

function move(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    boatPosX += 5;
    view.x -= 5
    moveCount++;
    console.log(moveCount);
    console.log("right");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Any pixel you don't redraw will remain unchanged. So when you move your boat, but don't draw anything on the pixels where the boat was last frame, those pixels will continue showing that boat's pixel.

You need to redraw those pixels. Either use `fillRect` with `fillStyle` set to the blue background color, or draw a full sized background image every frame.

```
ctx.fillStyle = "#60A0D8";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, view.x, view.y);
```

Do this before you draw anything else.

Comment: I do and it doesn't change anything. I just noticed that my mapArray was too small on X axis. So itends before I start moving background with translate() and thus it doesn't have what to show because the mapArray is too small and that's probably why it keeps trailing. I added more values to array and it doesn't leave trails in that spot anymore. `[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Answer (score 0):

Two choices, either you erase the previous image or you clear the whole canvas using the `context2d.clearRect`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect

Comment: So like I said before, the problem with this is that I iterate all over my `mapArray` and when it's over if I still keep moving right it just shows trails because I don't draw anything more on it. If I use clearRect then when my mapArray is over on the translate, I get white background because it simply clears it and do not redraw anything, right?

Comment: I think the best solution for this would be to check if my array map is over and my characters reaches the boundaries of mapArray and if it does, stop the translate() and do not show anything out of array boundaries so that the user could not see trails or white empty background. What do you think? So what I mean is when array rendering is over, set the translate() back to default or just better to the old position, kinda like a collision so it can translate any further showing empty canvas

Comment: Another solution will be to cache your backgrounds into a second canvas or inside an image ( 1. draw backgrounds then export canvas to img canvas.toDataURL() save that in a local variable, and before to move your cursor to new position, 2. compute new position, 3. clearRect, 4. render background, 5. render new element.)